# Facing problem on changing TextView text on buttonclick

Tags: android

I have a button(button) and a textview(text) in my application. Before clicking on the button the textview text will always be "Start Search".But After clicking on the button , a function(scanning()) will be called. For executing the function it takes some times. So I want the texview text to be "Please wait" between the time after clicking the button and before getting the result of the function. And after getting the result of the function the textview text will be change to "Found" or "Not Found".

But problem is ,it never shows "please wait". After clicking on the button it shows "Start search" until getting the result of the  function.

How to show "please wait" on the textview until it gets the result from the function after clicking on the button ??

```
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchR);
        text.setText("Start Search");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                text.setText("Please Wait");
                boolean res=scanning();
                if(res==true)
                text.setText("Found");
                else text.setText("Not Found");
            }
        });
```

XML Part:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Search"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchR"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="97dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In the scanning part, I did some searching for BLE devices using UUID. If that device is  found then I returned true otherwise false;

Comment: Share your xml file too where you are using the TextView and Button

Comment: Please share your `scanning()`

Comment: debug your code. If you see that everything is ok, you must be missing something in XML file. If you share we can say something else

Comment: I have shared XML part !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a small delay after you change the text to "Please Wait" and before calling `scanning()`.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                text.setText("Please Wait");

                Handler delayHandler = new Handler();
                delayHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        boolean res=scanning();
                        if(res) {
                            text.setText("Found");
                        }
                        else{
                            text.setText("Not Found");
                        }
                    }
                },100);
            }
        });
```

Edit: Depending on your code, you may need to declare your variables as static or maybe global for this to work.

Comment: Though you are using another 100 milliseconds wait, It works fine !

Comment: You can decrease the milliseconds if you wish. 50 millis or less will also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found some mistakes in your code.

1. You are changing text of Button instead of TextView.

   ```
       public void onClick(View v) {

           text.setText("Please Wait");
           boolean res=scanning();
           if(res==true)
           but1.setText("Found");
           else but1.setText("Not Found");
       }
   ```

Here

```
but1.setText
```

should be replaced with

```
text.setText
```

2. Your scanning method is returning result very fast, that's why you will not get Please Wait text.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding ! In my application text was but1 . But Before sharing my code I changed it to text. But unfortunately some of them are missing.

Comment: @mahbubcseju share your scanning method.

Answer (score 0):

Write external method for change text, 
for example:

```
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            changeText("Please Wait");
            boolean res = scanning();
            if (res) // (res == true) is unnecessary, you can use like this
                changeText("Found");
            else changeText("Not Found");
        }

        private void changeText(string s)
        {
            text.setText(s);
        }
```